# Auto select an item from a jQuery Autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery

I have a page that is using a couple of jQuery's autocomplete comboboxes.  I need to be able to autoselect an item from the list when the user clicks a button, or if a value is passed to the page for that combobox.  How can I set the value of both the underlying selectbox AND the jQuery combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found a solution.  When each autocomplete combobox is created, I give it a unique id, then use that id to set the value using $('#comboBoxUniqueId').val($('#selectBox').val())